# .htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I added

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /article/
RewriteRule ! ^article/\d+ redirect.php [L]
```

to `.htaccess` and got a .htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters message. Reviewed the related questions here but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Compare

```
RewriteRule ! ^article/\d+ redirect.php [L]
RewriteRule !^article/\d+ redirect.php [L]
```

Yes, the second works. You can't have a space between the ! and the pattern. AFAICS this is not mentioned in the Apache docs.

Comment: The `!` prefix-operator is part of the _argument_ and spaces are argument delimiters. In your first example `redirect.php` consequently gets interpreted as the 3rd (flags) argument, which is obviously invalid - hence the error.